# Lua, metatable, shadow environment

Tags: lua

I would like to provide a certain set of functions inside the global environment. After adding these tables and C-Functions the global env should be read only. The goal is to make a replaceable cheap work environment and a static **global** environment. (The static environment should contain some table that are time intensive to generate.)

From now on calls to create global variables should be forwarded to `local_env` and calls to access global variables that are not in `_G` should be forwarded to the `local_env`.

To do this I use the following metatables:

```
local_env = {}

setmetatable(_G, {
  __newindex = function(t, v, n)
  --print('attempt to write to _G', v, n, 
  --      'forward to local env', local_env)
  rawset(local_env, v, n)
end,
__index = function(t, k)
    --print('attemp to index unknown value', t, k,
    --       '-> lookup in local env', local_env)
    return rawget(local_env, k)
  end,
})
```

I think that using `rawset` I can overcome this protection but I can live with this issue.
Running some Lua-Code I get messages that the metafunctions are in use:

```
attempt to write to _G  flag    function: 42a2fbe4      forward to local env    table: 42b91fbc
attempt to write to _G  state   0       forward to local env    table: 42b91fbc
attemp to index unknown value   table: 4298aa2c state    -> lookup in local env table: 42b91fbc
```

But printing `local_env` doesn't show anything:

```
for k,v in pairs(local_env) do 
  print("-- local_env", k,v) 
end
```

What logical error do I do?

Comment: It is not necessary to use `rawget`/`rawset` in this case. But it doesn't harm either. Your code doesn't seem to have any error: it works for me.

Comment: If you don't care about the `print`, you can even simplify: `setmetatable(_G, {                                                  __newindex = local_env,                                                       __index = local_env                                                             })`

Comment: Shame on me!! I was fooled by my own concept!! I used the print at the beginning of the execution - stupid. After moving it to the end I works...

Comment: Be advised: each table can only have a single metatable. And since _G is generally shared...

Comment: @NicolBolas: What do you suggest? What's a more appropriate solution for my problem?

Comment: The general solution is to *copy* stuff from the global table into the local environment if you want it to be accessible.

Comment: @Mario There is actually another way to solve this problem. In Lua, you can actually change the current environment; instead of intercepting assignments to `_G`, you can actually change your environment from `_G` to a different table of your choosing. I would explain how to do this, but the tools for doing this were completely overhauled in Lua 5.2, so it depends on your current version. For Lua 5.1, use [`setfenv` and `getfenv`](https://www.lua.org/pil/14.3.html), and for Lua 5.2 and above, use [`_ENV`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.2).

Answer (score 0):

> The general solution is to copy stuff from the global table into the local environment if you want it to be accessible.